# What's the correct format of the format file for double quotes for every field in a csv file when doing bulk inserts in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert, bcp

I am trying to use bulk insert to import a csv file where each field is delimited by double quotes. This is an example of one row int the file:
"SONC","Sonic Corp.","981","amc","0.22","0.24","+0.02","+9.09%","5.15%",""

The format file I used is below which was created by bcp based on the destination table and updated it to define the double quotes. The imported data is not quite right because the columns still have some double quotes in them as shown here: [image]

I am not finding good docs which explain how to define the beginning and ending double quotes for each field. I think I need to specify the ending quotes in the format file but not sure where it goes in the fmt file. I want my data in the table not have any double quotes in them. Using SQL Server 2017.
What should the format file look like?

**My format file:**

```
14.0
10
1       SQLCHAR             0       10      ",\""      1     Symbol                       SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2       SQLCHAR             0       50      ",\""      2     Company                      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR             0       50      ",\""      3     Market_cap                   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
4       SQLCHAR             0       5       ",\""      4     Time                         SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
5       SQLCHAR             0       10      ",\""      5     Estimate                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
6       SQLCHAR             0       10      ",\""      6     Reported                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
7       SQLCHAR             0       50      ",\""      7     Surprise                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
8       SQLCHAR             0       50      ",\""      8     Surp                         SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
9       SQLCHAR             0       50      ",\""      9     Price_change                 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
10      SQLCHAR             0       50      "\r\n"   10      Report                         SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Comment: try bulk insert with the FIELDTERMINATOR flag: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql

Comment: To build on what @OwainEsau said, this file is not "delimited by double quotes". It is delimited by commas, and there is a text qualifier, which is the double quote.

Comment: @Owain Esau I added FIELDTERMINATOR = ',' and it didn't have any effect. I don't need to use that if the format file has all the formattings defined in it.

Comment: @Pittsburgh DBA OK wrong choice of words. Do you know what needs to be done in the format file?

Answer (score 0):

I used the format file I had and replaced the remaining double quotes with empty strings in the table. I don't believe format files can handle my input file and it's a limitation of SQL Server with format files.

Answer (score 0):

BCP does not like text qualifiers. Also, if you run into some delimiter pattern in your "qualified" text column, it's going to bomb.

Here is a way to accomplish it, assuming you have clean data in your file:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverfaq/2010/02/04/how-to-remove-unwanted-quotation-marks-while-importing-a-data-file/

The crux of it is specifying different delimiters for each column, and the first one is just a dummy.

My personal favorite file formats for BCP, in order, are as follows:

1. Native
2. Fixed Width
3. Pipe Delimited
4. Tab Delimited